# web servers available for android?

Tags: android, web-applications, webserver

Can someone tell me available options for web servers in android(even different type of servers like PHP , JAVA , JS etc) ?

I am looking to host web application in android phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about iJetty? ( http://www.intomobile.com/2008/03/17/run-a-web-server-on-your-android-mobile-phone-with-ijetty/)

Comment: Yes this is one of the option , but i am looking for other options too .Thanks for the info.